# returning DB results to an ajax call and print them after using json_encode

Tags: jquery

Purpose:

I am trying to return the results from a DB query to an ajax call and print the results on the blade View page of Laravel.

I have this at the View:

```
 $.post($url, {oui: valor, id: id},function(data){
           var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
           $('#yes').text(obj);
```

but this would also work

```
$.post($url, {oui: valor, id: id},function(data){         
           $('#yes').text(data);
```

however, it only works for one field (oui) of the db, not for the rest. (the code is similar but put #non instead). Supposedly json should be returning something like "oui":400, "non":500 or whatever the sum of each column is, but I am not being able to access them individually and print them separately.

Here is the controller:

```
$data = DB::table('polls')
        ->sum('oui')
        ->sum('non')
        ;       
        return( json_encode($data));
```

So, I want to echo or print both values, the sum of oui and the sum of non and that should be right at the ajax calls. so that they get printed on the same page in real time.

I have tried it a thousand times, all combinations but I am unable to get them printed all of them, I managed to print one field but not more than that. I thought of something like obj.oui, obj.non but it is not working like that, in fact it crashes the application.

Thank you

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` look like? I suspect you're not building that array correctly.

Comment: I have to remove the ->sum('non') in order to get at least the sum for ('oui') otherwise nothing gets shown. If I remove that, I get something like string(4) "1450" and 1450 is just the sum of the values in its column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the controller:

```
$data = array('oui' => DB::table('polls')->sum('oui'),
              'non' => DB::table('polls')->sum('non'));
return json_encode($data);
```

Then the view should be able to access `obj.oui` and `obj.non`.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Barmar! impressive cv ! and the answer has helped me to understand the mechanics of how this works. Thank you for taking the time of answering to someone like me with 1 reputation and yours an awesome 123k. Have a nice day.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question but you should use `return Response::json($data);`, so Laravel will provide the response with the appropriate Content-Type header.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel, so I didn't know about that. But if he does that, he should remove `jQuery.parseJSON()`, because jQuery automatically parses JSON if it sees that header.